# Display json in webpage

Tags: html, json

I'd like my html code to open a file that has a certain format.

But when it does open its all togeather with no correct spacing

Thanks for the help!
Here is some of my html code:

```
<td><a href="folder/something.json">Here</a></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor tag you have in your question will lead directly to a JSON file. As far as rendering JSON, by default you are at the mercy of your browser. There are however some [tools available](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Apr/01/Displaying-JSON-in-your-Browser) for rendering raw JSON.

If you have other content that you want to be displayed "as is" in your browser have a look at the [`pre`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag.

For example:

```
<pre>
this will
  display
    as-is
</pre>
```